# Imported products in Magento 2.1.1 doesn't show in the front-end

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1.1

I have imported more than 170000 configurable products, products are displayed properly in admin, but products are not displayed in front end. If I import only 30000 records at once, it will work fine.

I just tried `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` but not working. after reindexing **catalogsearch_fulltext** status shows **Working** is there any issue with this ?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow my below suggestions for display products on the fronted.

The product should assign with correct **website** and **category**.

Product **status** must be **enable**.

Product **visiblity** must be **Catalog Search**.

Product **stock status** must be **In Stock** With **Quantity**.

Check it for **configurable** and **simple product**.

Run below commands

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

Delete browser cache.

Comment: Sorry still facing the same issue, while looking in to the "alp_indexer_state" table status for" catalogsearch_fulltext" is working, did this will cause  for an error

Comment: is flat catalog enable or disable in admin ?

Comment: Use Flat Catalog Category and Use Flat Catalog Product shows  "No "

Comment: command "php bin/magento indexer:reindex" running without any error ?

Comment: yes, but catalogsearch_fulltext" status shows "working"

Comment: Thanks SH. Issue solved, in my case visibility was missing for few products

Comment: @Krishnakuma C Welcome